# Calling COM objects

Tags: c++, winapi, com, clsid, iid

I'm still learning about using COM objects.
I'm trying to figure out where the values of CLSID_FileOpenDialog and IID_IFileOpenDialog are defined: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/example--the-open-dialog-box
I couldn't find them in the included header files.

From one example I saw, I figured that I'd need .c and .h files with the interface and class GUIDs, but I couldn't find any reference of them for online.

Comment: instead `CLSID_FileOpenDialog` use `__uuidof(FileOpenDialog)` and instead `IID_IFileOpenDialog` use `__uuidof(IFileOpenDialog)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are *declared* as `extern` variables in `ShObjIdl_core.h`, which is included by `ShObjIdl.h`, which the example you linked to is including.

The actual values are *defined* in `uuid.lib`, which your project needs to link to, otherwise you will get linker errors when it can't resolve the variables.

Comment: @IInspectable that solution only works for guids that are declared with the `DEFINE_GUID()` macro, which is unfortunately [not the case](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.16299.0/um/ShObjIdl_core.h) in this situation.